# Display edit menu (copy/paste/select) on TextView upon focus()

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I'm using cross-platform framework NativeScript 1.5 and I'm trying to show the edit menu on TextView upon it is on focus. In this case with iOS, I tried to create a thing called UIMenuController like this:

`var menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController();
console.log(menu);`

The system printed out that menu is a UIMenuController object. After that, I want the edit menu pop up right away after the cursor is blinking on the textview, so:

`textview.focus();
menu.menuVisible = true;`

However, nothing happened. Am I doing wrong or something? Or is there any way better to do this? Any comments is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update my exact code**

XML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
    <Button text="Menu" tap="menu" />
    <TextField id="te" text="Hi this is a test of the emergency system.  panic now."/>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

JS:

```
var page;
exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
};

exports.menu = function() {
  var menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController();
  var te = page.getViewById('te');
  te.focus();
  menu.setTargetRectInView(page._nativeView.frame, te.ios);
  menu.setMenuVisibleAnimated(true, true);
}
```

Ok, the main issue is you need to set a target initially; without the target it doesn't know where to display the menu apparently.  In my tests because I clicked into the field initially to type data; the menu got a target so the setMenuVisibileAnimated worked.  But if you don't "tap" into the field it apparently doesn't get a Target Rectangle.   So by telling it where it needs to display; it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help but somehow this doesn't work for me. The textview should be focused programmatically and the edit menu shows up right after that, the user doesn't need to make a long press on TextView. Are u using 1.6.2 version?